# How do you simplify a boolean expression (!A B)+(B !C)+(BC)+(A !B !C)?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, boolean-computation

How would you simplify the following boolean expression (!A B)+(B !C)+(BC)+(A !B !C)?

I factorised B and managed to get B(!A+!C+C)+(A !B !C) = B+(A !B !C), but I do not know where I should go next.

Using a kmap, I managed to get the result of B+A!C and I am trying to achieve the same result using regular identities and laws of boolean algebra. By the way, sorry for poor formatting, but I do not know how I could paste an expression from word to make it look better and easier to read.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because, according to the OP's comment on one of the answers, it is unrelated to the software [Mathematica](http://wri.com) and therefore off-topic on this site.

Comment: @Szabolcs ups, sorry. I thought this is the exchange for maths. Where should I post this question instead? Once again, sorry.

Comment: Try math.stackexchange.com :)

Answer (score 2):

Is this enough

```
Simplify[!a&&b||b&&!c||b&&c||a&&!b&&!c,Element[a|b|c,Boolean]]
```

which instantly returns

```
(a && !c) || b
```

Comment: Well, I know what the result is supposed to be, but how do I actually get there? What methods do you use?

Comment: `FindEquationalProof` can be used to at least prove that these are equal. The proof that Mma spews out consists of 92 steps, though...

Answer (score 1):

```
BooleanMinimize[! a && b || b && ! c || b && c || a && ! b && ! c]

(*    (a && ! c) || b    *)
```

If you want a specific form:

```
F = ! a && b || b && ! c || b && c || a && ! b && ! c;
{#, BooleanMinimize[F, #]} & /@ {"DNF", "CNF", "ANF", "NOR", "NAND", "AND", "OR"} // TableForm

(*    DNF     (a && ! c) || b
      CNF     (a || b) && (b || ! c)
      ANF     a \[Xor] b \[Xor] (a && b) \[Xor] (a && c) \[Xor] (a && b && c)
      NOR     (a \[Nor] b) \[Nor] (b \[Nor] ! c)
      NAND    (a \[Nand] ! c) \[Nand] ! b
      AND     ! (! a && ! b) && ! (! b && c)
      OR      ! (! a || c) || b                                *)
```

Comment: I do not need the syntax, but the step by step method to work it out myself. Is this the wrong exchange?

Comment: Yes, wrong exchange.